# In glcoud cli is there a way to list Instance created in last one hour?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am looking for a gcloud CLI command to retrieve all the instance created in the last one hour

`gcloud compute instances list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `--filter "creationTimestamp > -P1h"` switch to your list command.